# Delete 2 Dynamic Buttons from one Dynamic Button

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dynamic

So I have an Image Map and on it I want to appear 3 buttons each time I clicked on a location. Those 3 button would be : hotspot, delete hotspot, save hotspot. These Buttons are Dynamically generated. The question is, how can I the hotspot from delete hotspot Button and also close the other 2 Buttons.

Some code for a little bit of understanding of what am I doing:

```
private void PictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            //Locatia
            PictureBox C = new PictureBox();
            int i = 0;
            C.Location = new Point(e.X-13, e.Y-30);
            C.Name = "Problema_" + (i + 1).ToString();
            C.ImageLocation = @"C:\Users\Starrux\Pictures\PNGs\Planner\icons8_GPS_500px.png";
            C.Size = new Size(26, 30);
            C.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            C.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            C.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
            // C.Click += new EventHandler(this.StartRecordingToolStripMenuItem_Click_1);;
            PictureBox1.Controls.Add(C);

            //salveaza Locatia
            PictureBox S = new PictureBox();
            S.Name = "Salveaza_" + (i + 1).ToString();
            S.Location = new Point(e.X - 45, e.Y+10);
            S.ImageLocation = @"C:\Users\Starrux\Pictures\PNGs\Planner\icons8_Checked_Checkbox_500px.png";
            S.Size = new Size(35, 35);
            S.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            S.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            S.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
            PictureBox1.Controls.Add(S);

            //sterge Locatia
            PictureBox St = new PictureBox();
            St.Name = "Sterge_" + (i + 1).ToString();
            St.Location = new Point(e.X +10, e.Y+10);
            St.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
            St.ImageLocation = @"C:\Users\Starrux\Pictures\PNGs\Planner\icons8_Close_Window_500px.png";
            St.Size = new Size(35, 35);
            St.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            St.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            PictureBox1.Controls.Add(St);

            S.Click += new EventHandler(this.stergeAprob);
            C.Click += new EventHandler(this.clickHotspot);

        }
```

Comment: `PictureBox1.Controls.Remove`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution could be that when creating dynamically you also delete it dynamically using anonymous functions

```
S.Click += (o, e) => {
     //....actions
     PictureBox1.Controls.remove(C)
     //... other actions
}
```

we can have access to dynamically created variables since the compiler creates inline functions